# How do I resolve my URLs being escaped in Drupal Popup views Integration

Tags: views

I have drupal popup views generating a popup on a view on hover, I would also like to have an onclick link to an anchor on the page. I have used a couple of hidden fields in my view to render the contents of the popup, but somehow get my url mangled when I want it to render http://www.myurl.suffix/node#[nid]

My url ends up being: %23%5Bnid%5D